# What Does 'What Stack Do You Work In?' Mean in Web Development?

Tags: development-environment, agile

What Does 'What Stack Do You Work In?' Mean in Web Development?

And, more specifically, what is a 'Stack' in web development?

Comment: The term refers to things like the base server operating system, the web server, the server-side programming language, and the persistent storage system (database).

Comment: http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/W/Web_stack.html

Comment: I don't get why this question was closed as 'opinion-based', it's asking for the definition of a commonly used term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what this has to do with the agile tag but, here's what I understand your question to mean:

I know of three stacks. WAMP, WIMP and LAMP

- LAMP - Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP (I think this is the most common and best known)
- WIMP - Windows, IIS, MS SQL Server, PHP (Bizarrely - you'd think it would be .NET or MVC)
- WAMP - Windows, Apache, MySQL / MS SQL Server, PHP